# Windows 10 WebDAV is broken to Internet services (such as hosting provider)

Tags: ssl, networking, windows-10, webdav, network-share

There are lots of discussions on many forums about issues with the webclient and failure to connect to WebDAV services which are on the Internet (such as a hosting provider). I wanted to share my frustration and hope for a solution...

> I have spent 3 days trying each and every solution and still cannot
>   connect to the WebDAV service.

Windows 10 x62 pro will intermittently connect, **but 90% (or more) of the time will bring up a error message** "Windows can not access \example.com@SSL@2078\DAVWWWroot check the spelling of the name..."

*The same service is reachable from Windows 10 x62 in a web browser which I type https://example.com:2078
The same service is reachable from a client on my smartphone using: \example.com@SSL@2078\DAVWWWroot
The same service is reachable from a client on a ubuntu box using: \example.com@SSL@2078\DAVWWWroot*
BUT The service can not be reached from windows then using the inbuild webclient  \example.com@SSL@2078\DAVWWWroot

1. I made sure the webclient service was running.

**1. Tried all other means to connect such as net use - did not work!**

```
net use U: \\example.com@SSL@2078\DavWWWRoot mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
net use U: \\example.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot      mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
net use U: \\example.com@2078\DavWWWRoot     mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
net use U: \\example.com\DavWWWRoot          mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
net use U: \\example.com@SSL@2078\           mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
net use U: \\example.com@SSL\                mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
net use U: \\example.com@2078\               mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
net use U: \\example.com\                    mypassword /USER:myuser /PERSISTENT:YES
```

**2. Setting WebClient parameters for Basic Authentication to either 1 or 2 - - did not work!**

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters" /V "BasicAuthLevel" /T REG_DWORD /D "00000001" /F 
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters" /V "BasicAuthLevel" /T REG_DWORD /D "00000002" /F
```

**3. Limiting the SSL Cryptographic Mechanism (as by default Windows still can use SSLv3 and other outdated protocols) - did not work!**

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002" /V "Functions" /T REG_SZ /D "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P521,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P521,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P521,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P521,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P521,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P521,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P521,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P521,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

**4. Tried creating entries in the local hosts file c:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts - did not work!**

```
123.1.1.1 example.com
```

**5. Tried setting the webclient AuthForwardServerList - did not work!**

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters" /V "AuthForwardServerList" /T REG_SZ /D "https://example.com"
```

**6. Tried setting the Network provider order, so that the webDAV client was second - did not work!**

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order"  /V "ProviderOrder" /D "LanmanWorkstation,webclient,cbfs6,vmhgfs,RDPNP"
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEMCurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder" /V "ProviderOrder" /D "LanmanWorkstation,webclient,cbfs6,vmhgfs,RDPNP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this all being done through a batch file? If so, it's most likely a permission issue for the HKLM keys. You will need them to run as admin. Try right clicking the batch file and run as admin and see if that works.